# Is there a way to access a Blueprint class from C++ in Unreal?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint

I would like to be able to access a blueprint class via C++ code. I have the Blueprint class `BP_EquipmentBase` which is used for items that can be picked up, dropped, and used, and from my C++ player class, I would like to keep an array of held items, and a reference to the currently active item, but in my code, `BP_EquipmentBase` isn't interpreted as a valid class.

I have tried directly accessing the class by its name, like so:

```
UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadOnly)
BP_EquipmentBase* CurrentItem;

UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadOnly)
TArray<BP_EquipmentBase*> HeldEquipment;
```

which is invalid because it throws the error `identifier "BP_EquipmentBase" is undefined`. And since that point, I have been stuck trying to figure out how to access it from C++, because a lot of the things I've read told me to make a blank C++ actor class, and make it inherit from that, and use TSubclassOf, but I'm wondering if there's an easier method that doesn't require another C++ class.

Comment: What you usually do is providing a C++ interface that the BP implements. You then store an instance of the interface in your C++ class

Answer (score 1):

It is possible (and quite common) to access a Blueprint class in code and use the built-in reflection mechanisms to peer into it.

However, what you are attempting to do i.e. have the Blueprint class be a `UPROPERTY` is not possible. The `type` of the variable must be known at compile time. You *can* however use `TSubclassOf<UObject>` or a `UObject*` (which assumes you are storing instances).

```cpp
UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadOnly)
UObject* CurrentItem;

UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadOnly)
TArray<UObject*> HeldEquipment;
```

Although now there is no way to cast it to the Blueprint type. However, you *can* call functions by name by finding the function with the `FindFunction(FunctionName)` method on the `UObject*` and, once found, call `ProcessEvent`.

It will look something like this:

```cpp
if (UFunction* Function = ObjPtr->FindFunction(FunctionName))
{
    ObjPtr->ProcessEvent(Function, nullptr);
}
```

With all that said, unless you are writing tooling for Unreal and/or know Unreal's reflection system quite intimately, this is probably not a good idea. You wanted to avoid adding yet another C++ class. I don't think you should avoid it. Define a base class with overridable functions in C++ and then inherit from it.